# I need text to appear in 2 lines with a specific width and then text-overflow as ellipsis from second line --with pure css?

Tags: css

```
{
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I have used the above code..but it is not working as I required

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
{
       max-width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 15px;
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```